# Не могу сделать русский язык для pyowm

Tags: python, pyowm

Хотел сделать программу, на основе PyOwm. Вроде всё работало, но я не могу сделать русский язык, хотя всё сделал правильно.
Вот код:

```
from pyowm import OWM

owm = OWM('[token]', language = 'ru')  

place = input("Укажите город/страну: ")

mgr = owm.weather_manager()
observation = mgr.weather_at_place(place)
w = observation.weather

print(w)
```

Что это выдаёт:

```
owm = OWM('[token]', language = "ru")  # You MUST provide a valid API key
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'language'
```

Пишет что-то связанное с аргументом language, но я не понимаю

Comment: Код и ошибки в текстовом виде (не скринами) в самом вопросе (не в комментариях)

Comment: В версии `pyowm-2.10.0` на этот аргумент не ругается, зато ругается дальше, что там нет метода `weather_manager`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Язык [в OWM](https://github.com/csparpa/pyowm/blob/e35446ebe081c0b14a25dca0f7f8105836745b04/pyowm/owm.py#L31) переехал [в конфиг](https://github.com/csparpa/pyowm/blob/e35446ebe081c0b14a25dca0f7f8105836745b04/pyowm/config.py#L8).

Попробуйте так:

```
from pyowm import OWM
from pyowm.utils import config as cfg


config = cfg.get_default_config()
config['language'] = 'ru'

owm = OWM('<TOKEN>', config)
```

Answer (score 1):

Методы описанные выше у меня не работали (я думаю как и у вас, поэтому мне пришлось самому копаться на официальном сайте с документацией (там все на английском)

Вот ссылка если вы что-то не поймете или еще что:
https://github.com/csparpa/pyowm
там переходите в раздел
документация ("Documentation")/ там, под ним будет "Code recipes"/ потом какое-то время мотаете вниз и там будет ("Language setting")-то, что нам и нужно)

короче сам код:

```
from pyowm.owm import OWM
from pyowm.utils.config import get_default_config
config_dict = get_default_config()
config_dict['language'] = 'pt'  # вместо pt вставляете свой язык (ru)
owm = OWM('ваш API ключ', config_dict)`from pyowm.owm import OWM
```

кроме pt и API БОЛЬШЕ НИЧЕГО НЕ ТРОГАЕТЕ
надеюсь я кому то помог))))

Answer (score 0):

В самом начале, после импорта библиотек, я написал так:

```
config_dict = get_config_from('путь к файлу/configfile.json')
owm = OWM('API', config_dict)
```

И создал файл configfile.json с таким содержанием:

```
{
    "api_key": "ваш API",
    "subscription_type": "free",
    "language": "ru",
    "connection": {
        "use_ssl": false,
        "verify_ssl_certs": false,
        "use_proxy": false,
        "timeout_secs": 10
    }
}
```

Как я понял, это теперь так делается.

Answer (score -1):

У меня заработало так:

```
from pyowm.owm import OWM
from pyowm.utils.config import get_default_config

config_dict = get_default_config()
config_dict['language'] = 'ru'  # your language here, eg. Portuguese
owm = OWM('your-api-key', config_dict)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Это фактически нечего не добавляет к уже существующим ответам. Приведенный код с точностью до пустой строки и языка совпадает с кодом [в ответе от user411558](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1191602/1365)